# Developing iOS apps in JavaScript - How far can it go?

Tags: javascript, ios, healthkit

I'm a JavaScript developer and I heard it is possible to develop iOS apps in JavaScript via some "mobile app frameworks", though I may lose access to some functionalities that are otherwise available to native apps. What are these functionalities, and what's the best mobile webapp solution as of now that enables the webapp to do as much a native app could? Does any of them offer access to the newest feautures in iOS 8.0, like HealthKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See PhoneGap and Apache Cordova

http://www.phonegap.com
http://cordova.apache.org

You will not be able to do everything a native app can do, but you can do 80-90% and then fill in the blanks with native plugins.